# Storing variables as a list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I've been searching around a bit for way to store variables as a list for future use in different methods. So say one method produces X, another method has one produces Y and so on, I don't know if there is a way to declare a list, append each variable to that list and than call it at the to output everything I've saved in it.
Hope this makes sense. Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *for future use*? How far in the future? Do you really need that level of persistence? For example, if you are calling predicate `foo(..., L)` and it yields a list, and later in the same program you call `bar(.., L, ...)` then I would just use a variable that you carry along and update: `foo(..., L)` ... `bar(..., L, ..., NewL, ...)` etc. Using the `assert/1` as given in the answer is for persistent database, which might be what you need, but it's unclear from your question what you are trying to do.

Comment: @lurker Sorry it's unclear. Basically I have 3 methods that each return a single value I want to store, ideally in a list. The 4 the method will call on that list to be manipulated. Any help would be great.

Comment: Perhaps you could give a more concrete example in your question? And for clarity, keep with Prolog terminology (Prolog has no *methods*). If I call a predicate `foo(X, ...)`, I can later call `bar(X, ..., Y, ...)`. But what then? Do you want to call several predicates (queries) and preserve a list of results? How many? Do you have a specific example? If you want to gather the results in a list of several calls to a specific predicate, you would use `findall/3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `assert/1` to store things, like

```
assert(data(100))
```

then you can just say

```
data(X)
```

later to get `X = 100`

It sounds like what you want is to have each module call assert with a different predicate.

You can use lists also, but it will probably not be better in any way.

Addition: it is customary in this situation to use predicate names that are unlikely to be used in the interpreter, e.g. ones containing spaces, as in

```
assert('My Data from Module X'(100,200,300))
```